# how to get specific value from a string

Tags: string, flutter, dart

have this String
"name=jack&age=22&true&red"
and i want to get all the value as sperate String
i can get the first value by this but don't know how to get the other

```
String text = "name=jack&age=22&true&red" ;
var splitText = text.split("&") ; // [name=jack, age=22, true, red]
var firstValue= splitText.first ;  // name=jack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By index:

```dart
splitText[1] // age=22
splitText[2] // true
splitText[3] // red
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get what is after the equal sign as a whole chunk (the value of the key 'name' is jack) you can use this code:

```
void main() {
  String text = "name=jack&age=22&true&red" ;
  // This regex matches any alphanumeric followed by a '=' and those preceded by a '&'. 
  RegExp exp = new RegExp("&([A-Za-z0-9]*=)|([A-Za-z0-9]*=)");
  final splitted = text.split(exp);
  splitted.removeWhere((item)=> item.isEmpty);
  print(splitter); // Outputs: [jack, 22&true&red]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this could be an answer.
Why don't you try to use an index?

```
splitText[1] // age=22
splitText[2] // true
..
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like query parameters from a Uri.  If so, run this in dartpad to see an easy way to do this:

```
void main() {
  var u = Uri(query: 'name=jack&age=22&true&red');
  var qp = u.queryParametersAll;
  print(qp);
}
```

Output:

```
{name: [jack], age: [22], true: [], red: []}
```